# Rails 3 Routing resources scoped to a username

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic understanding of rails routing, but nothing too advanced. So far I've gotten by using the RESTful resource based routes and a few custom named routes.

I am nearly done my app now though and I wanted to make some pretty urls.

In my app, each user has many pages. What's the best way to make the URL's look like www.sitename.com/username/page_name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will route to the pages controller's show action. Params hash includes :username and :page_name.

```
match "/:username/:page_name" => "pages#show"
```

Remember to put it last or it will match pretty much everything.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're using this for, but something like this might work in your routes file:

```
resources :users do
    get 'page_name'
end
```

Which will produce: `users/:id/page_name`

You might want to check out the [Railsguide on routing](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a [member route](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) (section 2.9.1).

```
resources :users do
  member do
    get :cool_page
  end
end
```

Will result in /users/:id/cool_page

Comment: How is this different from my answer?

Comment: You did not place the mapping on a member. If you don't use member it won't use /:id/action it will use /:user_id/action